# How can I remove item form ListView in Xamarin Cross Platform Forms MVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I remove item form ListView in Xamarin Cross Platform Forms

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
        <MenuItem Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" Command="Binding DleteItemCommand}" />
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

But I want user code complies with MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

So, View model is just for presentation layer, you need interact with your cell instead of viewmodel. Follow the next steps:

1.Create a Observable collection of ViewModels for Cells. 
2. Add this collection to ItemSource of ListView.
3. Then for command add callback method

```
                    <ListView x:Name="citiesListView" ItemTapped="OnSelection">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Clicked="DeleteAction" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="true" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <StackLayout Padding="15,0">
                                  <Label 
                                    Text="{Binding .}"
                                    FontSize="30"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Then in code:

```
    public partial class YourPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> YourCollection { get; set; }

    public YourPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // initialize at this point
        YourCollection = new ObservaleCollection(<Some collection of view models>);
        citiesListView.ItemsSource = YourCollection;

    }


    private void DeleteAction(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = ((MenuItem)sender);
        var yourViewModel = (YourViewModelType) menuItem.CommandParameter;

       YourCollection.Remove(yourViewModel);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ObservableCollection<YourType>` and in command delete element from collection.

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection<YourType>();

yourList.ItemSource = collection;

// in Command
public void OnDelete (object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // getting reference on menu item
    var menuItem = ((MenuItem)sender).CommandParameter;    
    // cast to underlying viewModel
    var yourObject = (YourType)menuItem;
    collection.Remove(yourObject);
}
```

Comment: This is compatible with MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is compatible with MVVM pattern. So, you have a Cell in ListView and it is a single representation of viewModel. And using it is approach you have the next relationship: "model - viewModel - view". ObservableCollection has a references on ViewModels that you display in ListView's Cells, and you now can easily delete cells that you want. See improvements above in code

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how to use this in  the Model View in Command?